# Marking a EF 5.0 model as read-only

Tags: performance, entity-framework, readonly

One of the MS recommendations to increase Entity Framework 5.0 performance for the read-only scenarios described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853) is:

> If your application is only used for query scenarios, you can mark the model as read-only by adding a GenerateUpdateViews attribute on the EntityContainerMapping element in your XML mapping and setting it to false. Experience has shown generation of update views is more expensive than generation of query views, so be conscious about this and avoid generating update views when they aren’t needed.

Questions:

1. It's not quite clear is it related to the run-time or design-time/compile performance improvement?
2. If GenerateUpdateViews = false, then does it make any sense to apply other read-only recommendations such as:

   - context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false
   - AsNoTracking()

Thanks in advance!